# Reducing PNG file size in .NET

Tags: .net, image, png

I often use OptiPNG or pngcrush to reduce the file size of my PNG images.

I would like to be able to do this sort of thing programatically from within a .NET application. I'm dynamically generating PNGs that get sent to a mobile device, so I'd like to keep the filesize down.

Image quality is important, so PNG will definitely win over jpeg in this case.

Are there any existing libraries that I can use to do this?

Comment: Are you after file resizing for a set screen size, or file minimising like PNGOUT?

Comment: File minimising like PNGOUT. OptiPNG and pngcrush are similar tools.

Comment: I don't believe there are any managed libraries out there.  OptiPNG is open source, so a port of the code is *possible*.  Alternatively, though I doubt it will yield results, try loading your PNGs as bitmaps (this should cut the PNG meta-data stuff that might be wasting space) and then encode them as PNGs again: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx

Comment: PNG is a loss-less format.  The only way to make the file smaller is to remove details and color content so it can be compressed better.  Making it a lossy format.  Exactly the thing that the JPEG encoder does.

Comment: @Hans your first sentence is correct but your second is not. PNGOUT and similar *are* lossless - the output image *file* is usually  smaller in bytes, but its *pixels* are the same as the pixels of the input image.

Comment: @AakashM : Could you provide a link explaining how that works? Sounds interesting...

Comment: @Ian there's a little detail [here on wikip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNGOUT#Main_operation) and links from there; and stuff from our illustrious leader [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/getting-the-most-out-of-png.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try running any of the applications you've named from within your application using a command parameter. Or, if that's not possible, using windows automation.

Comment: Mm, that's a bit yucky from within a webservice. I'm receiving files over the web and resizing them, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out nQuant at http://nquant.codeplex.com. This will quantize 32 bit PNGs down to 8bit using entirely managed code with no need to shell to a C library. Currently its really just a quantizer and will always convert to an 8bit palette which may incur some quality loss. I am working on a lossless optimization feature which will hopefully be available soon.

Comment: I need lossless really, so I shall wait with bated breath!

Comment: Any updates to this?  What is the best way to reduce the png to the absolute minimum?